# how to use iframe on your page

Tags: php

i want to click on a link in that iframe 1 and the content viewed in other iframe, select the message sent and the clicked messee details viewed in other iframe and on the same window

```
<iframe src="all_m.php" scrolling="yes" width="200"></iframe>

<div style="float:right; margin-top:-0px; margin-right:-50px;">
<iframe src="read.php" scrolling="yes" width="200"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the property of parrent window using `onclick = parent.func()` also you can control other iframe src from a parent function func.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can pass the data between two iframes via session or cookie. I can give you solution particularly for the a tag click, you can provide your iframe name in the target attribute of "a" tag.

Suppose you want to pass your form to other iframe then:

```
<iframe src="all_m.php" name="iframe1" scrolling="yes" width="200"></iframe>
<div style="float:right; margin-top:-0px; margin-right:-50px;">
<iframe src="read.php" name="iframe2" scrolling="yes" width="200"></iframe>
</div>
```

put this a tag in your form in iframe1:

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();" target="iframe2">link</a>
```